# How to use GSON to encode String array data into JSON properly?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON in my Java project to encode data ( that are fetched from database and stored into a `String` array ) in `JSON` format. Everything looks OK but the problem is with the size of `String`. For example I have the following `String` array:

```
String [] data = new String[12];
```

Suppose my `String` array contains the following data: `{"ABC", "DEF", "GH", "IJ"}`

Then the encoded JSON data are: `["ABC", "DEF", "GH", "IJ", "\u0000", null, null, null, null, null, null]`

The number of null value in the JSON data is depends on the number of data available in my `String` array.

As the data is retrieved from database so I can't declare a specific size for my `String` array.

I am using the following code to encode `String` data into `JSON` format.

```
Gson gs = new Gson();
gs.toJson(data); //data String array contains data from database
```

Can anyone tell me how can I skip/remove those null value from my JSON data?

Comment: The `data` array is always defined as 12 in size? When you load the data form the database the excess capacity is padded with null? What about the `\u0000` String?

Comment: No, it is just an example. It may be less than 12 for one type of data and more than 12 for other data [depends on the requirements of the project]. Yes the excess capacity is padded with null. I don't know why '\u000' is added. As I load data in the format data[index++], to remove unwanted garbage, I use `data[index] = "\0"`. maybe `\u000` is added for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're uncomfortable working with array sizes, use an `ArrayList` and add each result from your database to it. Then when you're done with the database side of things:

```
data = arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
```

This guarantees that the `data` object is just the right size to hold your data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all an advice not directly related to the question. In a comment you say:

> As I load data in the format data[index++], to remove unwanted garbage, I use data[index] = "\0". maybe \u000 is added for this.

I strongly suggest you load data into a `List` as you don't seem very comfortable working with arrays.

Instead of `String [] data = new String[12]` use `List<String> data = new ArrayList<>()`. Then, when loading data, instead of `data[index++]` use `data.add(s)`.

Then the call `new Gson().toJson(data)` will work as you expect.

Anyway, to answer exactly your question you can just *clean* the array.

```
String [] data = {"ABC", "DEF", "GH", "IJ", "\u0000", null, null, null, null, null, null};
System.out.println("data = " + new Gson().toJson(data));
int i = 0;
for (; i < data.length && data[i] != null && !Objects.equals(data[i],"\u0000"); i++) ;
String[] cleanData = Arrays.copyOf(data, i);
System.out.println("cleanData = " + new Gson().toJson(cleanData));
```

The output of that code is this:

```
data = ["ABC","DEF","GH","IJ","\u0000",null,null,null,null,null,null]
data = ["ABC","DEF","GH","IJ"]
```